# Get available WI-FI networks SSID even when WI-FI is off

Tags: android, android-wifi

Is it possible to get Available Wi-Fi networks SSID even when Wi-Fi is in off state. On device when Wi-Fi is of it does not show available networks in range. I want them in off state.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to determine it if the service is off. You could however turn Wi-Fi connection on programmatically and then use `NetworkInfo` to determine it. Does that seem acceptable?

Comment: yes it can be done, but i was searching for WI-FI off state. Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Through your Router configuration page. Default Ip address for Tp link is 192.168.1.1.
Type it in your Web Browser address bar